# How to rename files after being copied based on creation time?

Tags: python, filesystems

After copying files from a user provided source and destination, the files need to be renamed based on the creation time. The files have multiple extension types that need to be preserved while being renamed and a record original filenames. The issue arises when attempting to rename the file after it has been copied to the destination. All attempted solutions creates an exception in callback. What's the best approach here?

```
def filter_copy(self):
    current_dir = self.Source.get()
    destination_dir = self.Destination.get()
    extensions = (['.avi', '.mpg'])

    os.chdir(current_dir)
    for root, dir, files in os.walk('.'):
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in extensions:
                src = os.path.join(root, file)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                logging.info("Copying the file %s..." % file)
                print("Copying the file %s..." % file)
                try:
                    with open('OriginalFilesReceipt.txt', 'w') as f:
                        f.write(file)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    logging.info("The directory does not exist to create to generate a receipt")
                shutil.copy(src, destination_dir)
    for names in os.listdir('.'):
        t = os.path.getmtime(names)
        v = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
        x = v.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        os.rename(names, x)
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `tkinter`, so you should create a [rme] that doesn't use it and describe the input and expected output you want — but presumably aren't getting (and why that is if you know the cause).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution based on the work from yzhong52 here: https://gist.github.com/tvdsluijs/1640613a32416b1197fc36b45e7b4999

The main error that was being received should have been obvious. The working directory wasn't the destination directory. The solution for the original question:

```
os.chdir(destination_dir)
        for names in os.listdir('.'):
            #split into filename and  extension
            filename, extension = os.path.splitext(names)
            if (extension in extensions):
                create_time = os.path.getctime(names)
                format_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time)
                format_time_string = format_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
                newfile = format_time_string + extension

                #if other file with same timestamp
                if(newfile in newfilesDictionary.keys()):
                    index = newfilesDictionary[newfile] + 1
                    newfilesDictionary[newfile] = index
                    newfile = format_time_string + '-' + str(index) + extension
                else:
                    newfilesDictionary[newfile] = 0

                os.rename(names, newfile)
                num_files = num_files + 1
                print(names.rjust(35) + '    =>    ' + newfile.ljust(35))
```